# Writing a curl Post call in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, github, github-api

If i issue a POST request using curl command to github api to add "Resolved" label; things are good.

```
curl -i -H "Authorization: token xxxxxxxxxxxx" -X POST 'https://git.corp.yahoo.com/api/v3/repos/owner/repo/issues/1/labels' -d '["Resolved"]'}
```

But when i try to do the same using Curl easy in my Ruby script

```
 set gh_api = https://git.corp.yahoo.com/api/v3/repos/owner/repo/issues/1/labels
 curl = Curl::Easy.http_post(settings.gh_api,'["Resolved"]') 
 do |c|
    c.headers = ["Authorization: token xxxxxxxx"]
 end
```

The JSON reponse I get is

```
"{\"message\":\"Not Found\"}"
```

What am i doing wrong in my ruby script?

Comment: @theTinMan edited my question to make it clearer. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

It's not at all clear what question you are asking because there is no question.

What's returned is a JSON response. Why don't you parse it with the JSON class and see what it returns:

```
require 'json'

puts JSON["{\"message\":\"Not Found\"}"]
=> {"message"=>"Not Found"}
```

I'm guessing that the problem is in the path of the URL if the response is "Not Found".

Answer (score 0):

My URL was wrong. I ended the URL with a '/'.